# wrap text so that all lines are roughly the same length

Tags: html, css, justify

How can I use CSS to wrap text so that equal lines are approximately equal length?
This was [asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996340/html-how-to-have-paragraph-split-into-equally-wide-lines) but got no good answers. For example, take this text:

> `<div class="evenwrap">`
>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>   `</div>`

If the line must wrap, I'd like it wrapped into lines of similar length. E.g., as two lines:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

As three:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

As four:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

And so on.

I've experimented with `text-align:justify`, `text-justify:newspaper`, and `white-space:nowrap`, but none have worked and I'm at a loss. Is there a CSS solution, or must I turn to javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's normal here that, if you want an old question to be answered, you gain some reputation and offer a bounty. Another option would be to change the question enough so it's not the same. Exact duplicates are not accepted in Stack Overflow.

Comment: What sort of bounty do I need to offer?

Comment: First you need to gain some reputation... actually I'm not sure what you can do in your situation, however duplicating questions is definitely not the answer.