# Break text into even line lengths with CSS only

Tags: css

I have a `div` that has `text-align: center` applied. It should be able to contain various text that may or may not wrap. When it wraps, I would like to have each line be roughly the same length, so it would show:

> The quick brown fox jumps
>
> over the lazy dog.

instead of:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy
>
> dog.

Basically, I'm looking for a pure CSS way to automatically place the break near the center of the text.

I know there are JavaScript solutions, and I have currently implemented a server side solution, but I'm always trying to learn more CSS to make things more flexible in the future.

Comment: What you need to do is to measure the text length, and then either insert the <br/> or change the width of the parent container. CSS cannot measure things, or make comparisons. I believe JS or server-side are your only options here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18009171/217866

Comment: with html you could use [`<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr).

Answer (score 4):

I'm quite sure you cannot do that with css, you can control no break points with html though.

```
<nobr>The quick brown fox jumps</nobr><nobr>over the lazy dog.</nobr>
```

Should give you the result you want.
Also you can stick `&nbsp;` between words that you don't want to wrap, for instance: `The&nbsp;quick&nbsp;brown&nbsp;fox&nbsp;jump over&nbsp;the&nbsp;lazy&nbsp;dog.` would give you the same result.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr) about `<nobr>`:  "Although this element is widely supported, it was never standard HTML, so you shouldn't use it."

They recommend solving it with CSS.

Comment: @kslstn thanks for pointing it out. Do you by any chance know how to do it with CSS? white-space: looks like a good option these days.

Comment: Depends a bit on your situation, but for me [tuxedobob's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46180607/1171638) worked.

Answer (score 4):

Put the pieces you don't want to break in `span` tags that forbid wrapping:

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap">The quick brown fox jumps</span>
<span style="white-space: nowrap">over the lazy dog.</span>
```

(I know this is old, but I just went looking for this.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `text-wrap: balance;` now. It's not fully supported in all browsers yet ([see browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-wrap#browser_compatibility)), but it's probably better than the other custom solutions.

[See documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-wrap)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function run() {
  const str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
  const arr = str.split(" ")
  const num = Math.floor(arr.length / 2)

  let res = ""

  arr.map((item, i) => {
    res += item + " "
    if (num === i) res += "\n"
  })

  console.log(res)
}

run()
```

Answer (score -1):

What if you reduce the width of your div ? Otherwise I'm not sure you can do it with CSS only